# Extending the SketchFlow player

Tags: .net, silverlight, expression-blend, sketchflow

I would like to add some controls to the SketchFlow player. For example, I would like to add a combo box with a list of values for a specific variable, and selecting a value will make a specific screen/state show up in the SketchFlow player canvas. Is this possible? I have seen that using the PlayerContext allows access to some controls/events in the Player, but I am not sure how extensible the Player itself is.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this was you asking the same question on the Expression forums, but pasting the link here in case other people come across this question:
http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/blend/thread/a9ed66f2-366d-40c4-b294-f40e79b781da